# Dojo: How to show modal dialog on page load declaratively

Tags: dojo

I've created Modal Dialog box declaratively in dojo, and I want to show it to the user on page load, but I don't understand why the following code is not displaying anything on the browser on page load. Could anyone please tell me what wrong am I doing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Dijit!</title>
    <!-- load Dojo -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">


    <script src="../lib/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
        <script>
     require(["dojo/ready","dojo/parser","dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojox/form/PasswordValidator","dijit/form/ValidationTextBox","dijit/form/Form","dijit/form/SimpleTextarea","dijit/form/Button"]);</script>
     </script>

</head>
<!-- set the claro class on our body element -->
<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-id ="dialogOne" data-dojo-type = "dijit.Dialog" title = "Create Users" style="display: none">
  <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
    <div class = "formQuestion">
         <span>Personal Details</span>
        </div>    
        <div>

          <label class = "firstLabel" for="Pname">Name </label>
          <input type ="text" id ="Pname" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
          data-dojo-props = "required :'true', invalidMessage:'',ucfirst:'true'" tabindex = '1'/>
          <label class = "secondLabel" for = "combo">Role </label>
            <Select id="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" tabindex = '2'>
                <option>Admin</option>
                <option>User</option>
            </Select><br>
            <label class = "firstLabel" for="Pemail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="Pemail" name="address" 
                    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                    data-dojo-props = "placeHolder:'(will be the username)',
                    trim:'true',
                    ucfirst : 'true'" tabindex = '3'/>
            <label class = "secondLabel" for="Pmobile">Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" id="Pmobile" name="address" tabindex = '4'
                    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                    data-dojo-props = " trim : 'true',
                    regExp : '(\\d){10}',
                    invalidMessage : 'Mobile number is invalid',
                    ucfirst : 'true'" /><br>
            <div dojoType="dojox.form.PasswordValidator"
            name="password">
            <div><label class = "firstLabel" for ="pass">Password </label><input type="password" id ="pass"
                pwType="new" tabindex = '5'/>
                <label class = "secondLabel" for ="confirm">Confirm Password </label><input type="password"
                pwType="verify" tabindex = '6'/></div>
        </div><br>
<div class ="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
            <button data-dojo-type = "dijit.form.Button" type ="submit" tabindex = '10' id = "ok" onClick="return dialogOne.isValid();">OK</button>
            <button data-dojo-type = "dijit.form.Button" type = "button" tabindex = '11' onClick = "dialogOne.onCancel();" id = "cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- This event is not firing -->
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onLoad" >
        dialogOne.show();
    </script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Does your navigator developer console output something ?

Comment: maybe try to set it programmatically

Comment: I just want to know why this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try call the `dialogOne.show()` in the callback of the `require` function, change the `"dojo/ready"` into `"dojo/domReady!"` and place it at the end of the module array

Comment: I'm getting an error on chrome console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: dialogOne is not defined". code: <script>
  require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){
   dialogOne.show();
  
  });
  </script>

Comment: I'm getting a message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined" on console.

Comment: add id="dialogOne" instead of data-dojo-id

Comment: Thanks for your help. There was problem in my require function. Now it is successfully showing modal dialog on page load. 
  require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/dom","dojo/domReady!"], 
   function(dom, registry) {
    dojo.ready(function() {
     dijit.byId('dialog').show();
    });
  });

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code. Make changes to the loading dojo part to point to correct path of your dojo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello Dijit!</title>
        <!-- load Dojo -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">


        <script src="../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
        <script>
            require(["dojo/ready","dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojox/form/PasswordValidator","dijit/form/ValidationTextBox","dijit/form/Form","dijit/form/SimpleTextarea","dijit/form/Button","dojo/domReady!"]
            , function(ready){
                ready(function(){
                    console.debug("Ready!");
                    dialogOne.show();
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <!-- set the claro class on our body element -->
    <body class="claro">
        <div data-dojo-id ="dialogOne" data-dojo-type = "dijit.Dialog" title = "Create Users" style="display: none">
            <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
                <div class = "formQuestion">
                    <span>Personal Details</span>
                </div>    
                <div>
                    <label class = "firstLabel" for="Pname">Name </label>
                    <input type ="text" id ="Pname" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                           data-dojo-props = "required :'true', invalidMessage:'',ucfirst:'true'" tabindex = '1'/>
                    <label class = "secondLabel" for = "combo">Role </label>
                    <Select id="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" tabindex = '2'>
                        <option>Admin</option>
                        <option>User</option>
                    </Select><br>
                    <label class = "firstLabel" for="Pemail">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Pemail" name="address" 
                           data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                           data-dojo-props = "placeHolder:'(will be the username)',
                           trim:'true',
                           ucfirst : 'true'" tabindex = '3'/>
                    <label class = "secondLabel" for="Pmobile">Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Pmobile" name="address" tabindex = '4'
                           data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                           data-dojo-props = " trim : 'true',
                           pattern : '(\\d){10}',
                           invalidMessage : 'Mobile number is invalid',
                           ucfirst : 'true'" /><br>
                    <div dojoType="dojox.form.PasswordValidator"
                         name="password">
                        <div><label class = "firstLabel" for ="pass">Password </label><input type="password" id ="pass"
                                                                                             pwType="new" tabindex = '5'/>
                            <label class = "secondLabel" for ="confirm">Confirm Password </label><input type="password"
                                                                                                        pwType="verify" tabindex = '6'/>
                        </div>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class ="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
                        <button data-dojo-type = "dijit.form.Button" type ="submit" tabindex = '10' id = "ok" onClick="return dialogOne.isValid();">OK</button>
                        <button data-dojo-type = "dijit.form.Button" type = "button" tabindex = '11' onClick = "dialogOne.onCancel();" id = "cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```